# Which cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator does Debian kernel use?

Tags: debian

On FreeBSD and recent releases of macOS, [Fortuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG)) is used.

What about Debian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random), ChaCha20:

> In October 2016, with the release of Linux kernel version 4.8, the
> kernel's /dev/urandom was switched over to a ChaCha20-based
> cryptographic pseudorandom number generator (CPRNG) implementation[16]
> by Theodore Ts'o, based on Bernstein's well-regarded stream cipher
> ChaCha20.

This is also discussed on the [Cryptographically-secure pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically-secure_pseudorandom_number_generator#Special_designs) page at Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for helping out… I had stumbled upon Wikipedia. Somehow I thought ChaCha20 was an encrypting cipher (like AES) not a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: @sunknudsen ChaCha20 is also an encrypting cipher... one attribute of a good encrypting cipher is that its output should look very random.  That same quality makes an algorithm a good choice for a CSPRNG.  It's just a different use to put it to.

Comment: The [current implementation of the `random` driver](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/char/random.c) can be perused to confirm that it is (still) using ChaCha20.

Comment: @sunknudsen, [counter-mode encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CTR) is basically turning a block cipher into a stream of random bits. Doing that starts showing imperfections after some huge number of blocks, but that can be fixed by rekeying (which also prevents rewinding the RNG, so is a good idea anyway). ChaCha20 is basically always used in a similar way.